# Expected std::vector<Type>, received std::vector<Type>

Tags: c++, templates

I'm using the [Essentia](https://essentia.upf.edu) framework in C++, my code compiles and runs fine in Debug mode.
But when I try and run it in release mode, this snippet throws an exception

```
void SpleeterWrapper::LoadFromWav(std::vector<StereoSample>& result, std::string path)
{
    std::unique_ptr<Algorithm> audioLoader(AlgorithmFactory::create("AudioLoader", "filename", path));
    Real sr;
    int nchnls, bitRate;
    std::string md5, codec;
    audioLoader->output("audio").set(result);
    audioLoader->output("sampleRate").set(sr);
    audioLoader->output("numberChannels").set(nchnls);
    audioLoader->output("md5").set(md5);
    audioLoader->output("bit_rate").set(bitRate);
    audioLoader->output("codec").set(codec);
    audioLoader->compute();
    audioLoader->reset();
}
```

The exception is

```
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type essentia::EssentiaException: In AudioLoader::audio::set(): Error when checking types. Expected: `std::vector<StereoSample>`, received: `std::vector<StereoSample>`
```

Which doesn't really help me much, wondering what I'm doing wrong, if this could be an issue with the Essentia library, if anyone has encountered anything like this and if anyone has any ideas on where I could look to pinpoint the issue here!

(I've tried making a temporary vector and then swapping the contents with result, same issue) (Edit: sorry for duplicate, had no idea what to google to find a solution, thanks for your input everyone)

Comment: depends on your platform, sometimes `typeid(foo) != typeid(Foo)` even though `foo` is of type `Foo` if `foo` originated in a different shared library to the shared library where the check is being executed

Comment: This seems to me like there might be duplicate `typeinfo` for `StereoSample`, which can happen if the linker can't merge the definitions for some reason.  It depends on exactly how your build works.  Are there multiple libraries etc.?

Comment: StereoSample is declared in Essential though, unless you mean the vector itself? I'm on osx using Xcode to compile it if that makes any difference, I'm linking to Essentia as a dylib not a static lib as well
(Edit: @TavianBarnes theres Essentia and all its dependencies, then another lib called Spleeterpp but it doesn't seem to have conflicts that I can find)

Comment: If you use different compilers for the Essential library and for the current build then an error might occur. You might even be linking release-to-dubug which is can be an issue too. Build issues are most annoying.

Comment: I know man my heart actually drops anytime I get an issue like this, it worked in Debug mode so I wonder if there's something to that, maybe I should see if there's a build mode flag I can set when building essentia?